# Loading gif to hide when all ajax scripts have been executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've tried several methods to get my loading gif to show and then hide when the ajax scripts have finished loading. I tried $j(window).load and I'm currently trying to place hide() function on the loading gif div element in different places. I can't figure out how to show the loading gif until the other scripts in the function have loaded. Can you see what I can do? (if I comment out all $j('#loading').hide() I do indeed get the loading gif shown). SimpleWithAttrPrices function executes an ajax script and returns value.

```
function updatePrices(IDs){
    var product_id= <?=$product_id ?>;
    var qty= parseInt($j("#qtyUpdateBox input").val());
    $j('#loading').show();

    if (qty==1){
        function sendRequest(i,basePrice) {
            var optionSelectionArray = currentlySelectedAttributes(IDs[i]);
            simpleWithAttrPrice(optionSelectionArray, function(data) {
                //var vendor = IDs[i];
                var basePrice = parseFloat(roundDollar(data));
                $j('.details'+IDs[i]+ ' .priceBlock').empty();      
                $j('.details'+IDs[i]+ ' .priceBlock').append('<span>'+formatCurrency(basePrice,"$")+'</span>');
                $j('.details'+IDs[i]+ ' .priceBlock').append('<input type="hidden" name="customPrice" value="' + basePrice + '"/>');
            });
        }//end sendRequest

        for(i=0; i<IDs.length; i++)
        {   
            sendRequest(i);
            if(i=IDs.length-1){
                $j('#loading').hide();
            }
        }

        //$j('#loading').hide();
}//end if
//... THE REST OF THE FUNCTION NOT APPLICABLE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) to show/hide loading animations during ajax requests.

It is as simple as this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $j('#loading').show();
})
.ajaxStop(function() {
  $j('#loading').hide();
});
```

Comment: This can be placed anywhere?

Comment: Yes, it can be place anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If it's easy for you to keep track of how many requests you send out, you could count how many times [`.ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) is called before hiding the `#loading` element.